# Using OO PHP in CSS

Tags: php, css, oop

**tl;dr - I'd like to know if it is possible to pass an object into a PHP file with CSS headers, such that I can use this object to manipulate various CSS attributes.**

What I'm attempting to do, is allow my PHP/CSS file to interact with the other objects/php files in the webpage, e.g. menu item objects. My ultimate goal is to use PHP in the CSS file to count the number of menu items, and apply the appropriate `width` value in order to space them out evenly on the page.

I use a very simple color based example below to demonstrate my understanding so far...

I understand that for basic usage of PHP in a CSS file, one can do something like:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css");
$dkgreen = '#008400';
body {
 background:<?=$white?>;
}
?>
```

I also understand that OO PHP can be used to achieve a similar thing, e.g.:

```
class css {

    function __construct($args=array()) {
        foreach($args as $key => $field) {
            $this->{"$key"} = $args["$key"];
        }
        return $this;
    }
}

$css = new css(
    array(
        bgcolor => '#00FF00',
        fgcolor => '#000000',
    )
);

body {
  background: <?php echo $css->bgcolor; ?>;
  color: <?php echo $css->fgcolor; ?>;
}
```

### Results of experimentation

1) OO style

I firstly attempted to make my css class create a singleton object for the CSS, which I tried to retrieve using `$css = css::singleton()`, along with the `getCss()` function,  instead of `$css = new css(...)`. The idea was that I wouldn't simply initialise another css object which would be useless to me. Attempts to get the values for bgcolor and fgcolor using:

```
$css = css::singleton(); 
$css->getCss()->bgcolor;
```

were unsuccessful.

2) altering the href in the link tag à la `style.php?bgcolor=00FF00&fgcolor=000000`

This worked beatifully, when I could easily type `$bgcolor = $_GET['bgcolor'];`, but doesn't seem to me an elegant solution.

Ideally, I'd like to retain an Object-Oriented approach, but if that's not possible, I'll happily settle for a POST approach, (i.e. allow me to use `$bgcolor = $_POST['bgcolor'];`) to avoid filling up the source code with ugly parameters in the link tag.

I'd also wish to avoid creating multiple .css files, if that is at all possible.

Any tips?

Many thanks,
Owen.

Comment: `My ultimate goal is to use PHP in the CSS file to count the number of menu items`. Impossible.

Comment: @Donut: Not if the menu items are generated from a table in a database, although OP makes no mention of that

Comment: what you want to do is best handled by a javascript/jquery layer, not PHP

Comment: i dont understand the question but a singleton is definitely not the right solution

Comment: you can use your PHP as a css file with `header('text/css')` just link it in as like `<link href='css.php' (rest of the stuff)>` but javascript is usually better for this sort of thing...

Comment: You want to be using client side JavaScript for this...not server side PHP.

Comment: At the end of the day, I'd just like to be able to pass objects into the PHP/CSS file. Is this possible? (I shall also update the post accordingly to include this simplified form of the question)

Comment: YOu are just making the wheel look like a box use javascript, if you don;t know javascript jQuery is easy to learn.

Comment: The purpose of css is to separate the presentation from the code, by doing this you're pretty much negating the usefullness of css.  Your code should just generate the appropriate ids and classes and you can style them in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, and that doesn't fit the purpose of CSS.

Edit:
Well basically, CSS is suppose to contain data that apply a style on a well defined structure. So CSS should not even have variables ( this is a big debate ). The "good theorical way" to solve your problem is to generate html code with proper id and classes, so that you don't have to make any calculation using CSS: you only have to apply a style.

Furthermore:
CSS file are made to be cached. If they change all the time, you may have cache problem, or need to ask the file not to be cached. The you might need to generate inline CSS using PHP, but not a CSS file itself.

Comment: I don't see how I'm defeating the purpose of CSS. I wish to make some calculations in PHP, and then pass an object containing all these values into the CSS, and put the values in the corresponding places.

Comment: It is totally possible and the purpose of CSS it to separate style from content. Sometimes you have to resort to dynamic css rules to do that.

Comment: @linepogl Your almost right. That why SASS and LESS exists. But don't forget that CSS file are to be cached, so they should not be as dynamic as asked.

Comment: @FMaz008, see my comments on MetalFrog's answer regarding caching :-)

Comment: Ok, thank you all for your answers. If then, I were to have $x menu items, which I want to be equal widths spread across the page, what would be the best way to achieve this in CSS if $x is unknown until PHP does its work? I also wish to avoid in-line CSS if possible. Again, many thanks!

Comment: @OwenD, from a purist point of view, I think this is the job of Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to make your CSS file a PHP file, and link to it.

```
<link href="style.php" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Then, you parse all your code and dump it out at the end.

```
$css = ''; # all of your compiled CSS after you do what you need to
header("Content-type: text/css");
print $css;
exit;
```

Now, your CSS is being parsed how you want it to be, and it's being served as CSS.

Comment: Sure, but how do I get the css object into the file to start with?

Comment: You have to also add http-caching headers according to your policy. Otherwise, the browser is going to believe that this is a static file and will reload it from the cache in each subsequent request.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your follow up question.

Comment: @linepogl Fair enough, but if he's passing arguments through the URL won't those same requests be the same each time? Wouldn't it be better for it to be cached?

Comment: @MetalFrog - It's easy enough to define things in PHP within the CSS and then use them throughout the file, but my issue is in retrieving values which are calculated outside this file, e.g. index.php.

This is why I'm hoping that there's a mechanism whereby I can put all the results of these calculations inside an object, and then hand that object to the PHP in the CSS, which then pulls it apart, and applies the values in the relevant places.

Thanks for responding.

Comment: @MetalFrog, of course, if the result of the `style.php` depends only on the query string arguments, then this is sufficient enough. However, if the result also depends on other things, then you need to refine the caching control...

Comment: @OwenD Perhaps you can store in the session or something, then style.php would load it from the session. That would keep it user-specific and persistent across the separate requests.

Comment: ... now why didn't I think of sessions? Thank you!